# Jquery, Sequence.js. Plugin does not start, no visible errors

Tags: php, jquery

Only thing I can think of is that I'm inserting the javascript at the end of the page, not in the head tag but that has never been an issue before.

The following HTML:

```
<div id="sequence">
    <ul>
        <li class="animate-in">
            <div class="frame f1">
                <a href="/projects/3">
                    <img src="../../assets/projects/02.jpg"/>
                </a>
                    <div class="project_info">
                        <h1>Landscape Design & Build</h1>
                        <h2>Private Villa - Muharraq</h2>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="frame f2">
                <a href="/projects/2">
                    <img src="../../assets/projects/03.jpg"/>
                </a>
                    <div class="project_info">
                        <h1>Landscape Design </h1>
                        <h2>Private Villa - Saar</h2>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="frame f3">
                <a href="/projects/1">
                    <img src="../../assets/projects/01.jpg"/>
                </a>
                    <div class="project_info">
                        <h1>Landscape Design & Build</h1>
                        <h2>Private Villa - Riffa</h2>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Is generated from the following PHP Template:

```
<div id="sequence">
    <ul>
        <?php
            $count = 1;
            foreach ($projects as $project) { ?>
                <li<?php if ($count == 1) { ?> class="animate-in"<?php } ?>>
                    <div class="frame f<?php echo $count; ?>">
                        <a href="/projects/<?php echo $project['id']; ?>">
                            <img src="../../assets/projects/<?php echo $project['image']; ?>" />
                        </a>
                        <div class="project_info">
                            <h1><?php echo $project['type']; ?></h1>
                            <h2><?php echo $project['name']; ?></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php $count++;
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
#sequence {
    /*visibility: hidden;*/
    position: relative; /* required */
    width: 830px;
    height: 320px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    #sequence > ul li > * {
        position: absolute; /* required */
    }

    #sequence > ul > li {
        position: absolute; /* required */
        width: 100%; /* required */
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1; /* required */
    }

    #sequence .frame {
        background: #CCCCCC;
    }

    #sequence .f1 {
        left: -1000px;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
        -o-transition-duration: 1s;
        -ms-transition-duration: 1s;
        transition-duration: 1s;
    }
```

And I'm initiating sequence like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // slider
    var options = {
        autoPlay: true,
        autoPlayDelay: 3000
    };
    $("#sequence").sequence(options).data("sequence");
});
```

Comment: make sure you are loading the sequence,js

Comment: I am.. there are no errors in firebug or anywhere else. I should at least get an error when i try to initialize sequence and if the .js is not loaded, right?

Comment: yes... saying sequence is undefined... :)

Comment: Exactly. and there is no error. So, it's not that. Sequence.js is there.

Comment: you give an alert in document.ready and se if that is being called or not

Comment: I assure you. Sequence.js is being called.

Comment: no i mean... the script is being called or not.. not the sequence.js... what is could see is...you are not enlcosing the javascript within `<script></script>` tag

Comment: Umm.. it's actually autoloaded. The doc ready is in a file called main.js which is autoloaded through php. I have other scripts running just fine. I didn't include them for brevity.

Comment: To clarify.. when i say autoloaded.. php writes the necessary line in a page template.

Comment: what service do you use to generate your code ?

Comment: It's just basic php templating.. custom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [README.md](https://github.com/IanLunn/Sequence#v09-1932013):

> v0.9 19/3/2013
>
> The top level `<ul>` MUST now be given the class `.sequence-canvas` for Sequence to work

`<ul class="sequence-canvas">`

Comment: You would think that would be in the documentation on the site... regardless.. I added it.. still doesn't work, so its not that.. I've updated the OP to reflect.

Comment: It does fix it partly for me... after 3 seconds the second image is displayed and you can navigate with the arrow keys.

Comment: instead of <ul class="sequence-canvas"> you typed DOTsequence-canvas <ul class=".sequence-canvas">. Shouldn't you remove the DOT?

Comment: fml.. i really am half asleep. Yes. The DOT. THANK YOU. It is moving now.. this has been a long night.. if you came here from G+, message me on there to discuss your bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a different webbrowser? I had the same problem when I was using Chrome.

Comment: Tried IE, Firefox, Safari, Chrome, and Opera. I have them all and I check them all..

Comment: Is it possible to provide us with the files? I think it's a tricky thing to let php autoload the lines. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Not really.. i"m simply replacing a {js} tag with a function that iterates through a list of js files.. I will post the function and the array in the OP.. but if you want the files, sure, keep in mind its all sitting on a fledgling php framework that i'm working on. Give me a few minutes to zip it and put it onling.

Comment: What if you try to load the scripts in the header?

Comment: tried that.. problem was solved.. it was the UL tag and the class that is meant to go there. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the script closing tag correct or a typo? <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/lib/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

Comment: That's correct. there was a reason for that.. it escapes the forward slash that is right after it.

Comment: I removed them from the post.. did you still want to see them?

Comment: Yes, please. Just to see the result.